# Want to Implement Pagination in my ASP.NET MVC TestProject Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I want to implement Pagination in my ASP.NET MVC project.When i put `@model PagedList.IPagedList<TestProject.Models.Test>` in my `Index` page then the following error appears.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'IPagedList' does not contain a definition for 'FName' and no extension method 'FName' accepting a first argument of type 'IPagedList' could be found

And When I put  `@model IEnumerable<TestProject.Models.Test>` then it gives following error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestProject.Models.Test>' to 'PagedList.IPagedList'

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, pageNumber => Url.Action("Index", new { pageNumber })
```

My `Home Controller` returns the following:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? pageNumber)
{
    TestHandle testHandle = new TestHandle();
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(testHandle.GetAll().ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 3));
}
```

My `GetAll` function retruns list:

```
public List<Test> GetAll()
{
    clsUtilities cUtils = new clsUtilities();
    DataSet ds;
    List<Test> studentlist = new List<Test>();
    string sSQL;
    sSQL = "exec AllPhone";
    ds=cUtils.GetDataSet(sSQL);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        studentlist.Add(
            new Test
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),
                FName = Convert.ToString(dr["FName"]),
                LName = Convert.ToString(dr["LName"]),
                Address = Convert.ToString(dr["Address"])
            });
    }
    return studentlist;
}
```

Please guide me. I did so much of research but no luck. So I am posting this error. Please suggest me where i am going wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to implement pagination. Check out Bootbox plugin for pagination it also gives you other features like sorting. Plus it is really easy to use.

Comment: @BigSmile, can you please suggest me some links for Bootbox? Anyway, I am trying to use Pagination in MVC project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayNameFor()` only accepts `IEnumerable<T>` when using it for a collection property. If your model is `IPagedList<T>`, then you can use

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().FName)
```

Note this will work even if the collection is empty.

As a side note, calling `ModelState.Clear();` in your GET method is pointless and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked for me now. Thank you once again.